# Create public synonyms for table and sequence in oracle

Tags: oracle

I need to create public synonyms for sequence.Could you please suggest how to create synonyms for sequence in oracle 11g.

Alter script to add constraint:
ALTER TABLE schema.table_name ADD( CONSTRAINT pk PRIMARY KEY(primaryKey_ID));

Sequence: 
CREATE SEQUENCE  table_name START WITH 1;

Comment: I removed the MySQL tag.

Comment: I noticed you posted 21 questions and never accepted an answer. Haven't you ever had a good answer or there's another reason why you never accept an answer?

Comment: I have accepted your answer when i got response from you

Comment: Something on [accepting an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). It is both a way to mark the question as closed, because it's got a good answer, and to say thanks to people who helped you. I believe you should consider accepting the good answers you received in your questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/database/122/SQLRF/CREATE-SYNONYM.htm#SQLRF01401) you can create a public synonym  for your sequence in the same way you do for a table:

```
create public synonym table_name for yourSchema.table_name;
create public synonym sequence_name for yourSchema.sequence_name;
```

Comment: This is the review comments which i got from user.You need to specify public synonyms for both the table and the sequence.I know how to set public synonyms for table and  don't know for sequence

Comment: @user1679378 There's no difference between creating a synonym for a table or a sequence